# Trying to use Feign to log into Spring OAuth2 server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-feign

I'm looking to make a `grant_type = password` login from  a service with Feign to the Spring OAuth2 server. I've confirmed the OAuth2 server works when I make a normal REST call. But when trying with Feign, it fails.

In my service I have:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@FeignClient(url = "http://localhost:9999/uaa")
public interface AuthClient {

    @RequestMapping(value="/oauth/token", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @Headers({"Authorization: Basic some_base64encoded_client_secret_here=="})
    public LoginResponse login(
            @Param("username") String username, @Param("password") String password, @Param("grant_type") String grantType);

}
```

I get this error: 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129 to org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping`

Most examples I find show how to intercept Feign to use OAuth headers/etc. and assume the access token already exists. But this is not my issue. I don't have an access token yet because I'm trying to get the access token from logging in. Any ideas on how I can log in using Feign?

Answer (score 0):

You can map your own response like this:

```
@Component
@FeignClient(name = "authClient", url = "http://localhost:8080")
public interface AuthClient {

    @RequestMapping(value="/oauth/token", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    AuthResponse login(@RequestParam("grant_type") String grantType, @RequestParam("username") String username,
                   @RequestParam("password") String password, @RequestParam("scope") String scope);

    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    class AuthResponse {
        String access_token;
        String token_type;
        String refresh_token;
        String expires_in;
    }
}

public class AuthService {

    private final AuthClient authClient;

    public AuthService(AuthClient authClient) {
        this.authClient = authClient;
    }

    public AuthClient.AuthResponse authenticate(String login, String password, String scopes) {
        return this.authClient.login("password", "admin", "admin", "read+write");
    }
}
```

You can register a request interceptor to add Authorization headers at every request:

```
@Bean
public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
    return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("clientId", "clientSecret");
}
```

This code works with a sample Spring Security OAuth2 server.

Comment: Just tried it, same error. I think it probably has to do with mapping the response from OAuth to my own response. I'm not sure how to go about ensuring Feign can map params to my own response?